# Display command result with imagemagick cli

Tags: imagemagick

So in my workfow I often do something like :

```
convert image.png -level 10x90% tmp.png # try a command on a temporary file
display tmp.png # display the image to see if it looks good
rm tmp.png # delete the temporary file
mogrify -level 10x90% image.png # finaly apply the command to the image.
```

What I would like is a way to directly see the result of the command without creating a tmp file.
Something like :

```
convert image.png -level 10x90% | display # this does not exist
```

or

```
display -level 10x90% test.png # this neither
```

**A way to quickly display an imagemagick command result before doing it.**

does it exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
magick -size 1024x768 xc:red miff:- | display miff:-
```

You can probably always reduce that to:

```
magick -size 1024x768 xc:red miff: | display
```

[MIFF](https://imagemagick.org/script/miff.php) is guaranteed to support all data types and any number of channels so it is a good general purpose choice.

---

So, in general:

```
magick IMAGE ...process... miff: | display
```

Note that you can use a different viewer if you wish, e.g. `feh`:

```
magick IMAGE ...process... PNG:- | feh -
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the first line works. I'm not abble to make it work without the dash (`miff:-` works but not `miff:`) Can you provide some precision on what this `:-` syntax means or a link to understand it better ?

Comment: When writing a file with **ImageMagick**, you can force it to generate a specific type of output by prefixing the output filename with a *"format specifier"* and a colon to separate it from the filename. So `PNG24:output.png` forces a 24-bit PNG to be written, rather than one with a palette (PNG8:) or a 32-bit RGBA (PNG32:) one. Or `TIFF64:output.tif` forces a *BIGTIFF* file. The dash (minus sign) is just Unix-speak for *"the standard output"*.

Comment: The same applies to input files. If you have a YUV file that is called `data.bin` and you don't want to change its name to `data.YUV` so **ImageMagick** knows what it is, you can force **ImageMagick** to treat the data as YUV by using a prefix and telling it to read `YUV:data.bin`

Answer (score 3):

On Unix-based Imagemagick you can use the show: command to view an image without saving it to disk.

```
magick -size 100x100 xc:red show:
```

Comment: I always forget that one now that `X11` support is no longer in **homebrew**  :-)

Comment: Yes, you do need to have X11 installed. On the Mac, there is XQuartz that replaces it. But I think Linux still has X11.